# What is the proper path to expand /root LVM

Tags: root, storage, lvm, xfs

I have recently added a 562 GB to a virtual machine in Vsphere. I expanded the /dev/sda2. I performed the 8e LVM... and now executed `pvresize /dev/sda2`

My goal is to expand the LVM for root partition.

I would like to know what is the proper way write the following commands: because whather I use either path `/dev/mapper/rhel-root` or `/dev/rhel/root` my server still reboots fine and changes seem ok.

```
lvextend -l +452G /dev/rhel/root
xfs_growfs /dev/rhel/root
```

---

```
lvextend -l +452G /dev/mapper/rhel-root
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/rhel-root
```

What is the difference on the above paths for the commands, since both sets deliver the same solution. Does anyone know?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 3):

If you do an `ls -l` on these entries you'll probably find they're both symlinks and both point to the same entry:

eg on my CentOS 6 machine:

```
% ls -l /dev/Raid10/vm.kali /dev/mapper/Raid10-vm.kali 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Aug  3 15:55 /dev/Raid10/vm.kali -> ../dm-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Aug  3 15:55 /dev/mapper/Raid10-vm.kali -> ../dm-10
```

This means it doesn't really matter which name you use.  They both operate on `/dev/dm-10` (in this case)

I, personally, prefer the `/dev/VG/LV` naming scheme; it's less to type :-)

Comment: You are right. They are symlinks. I have to learn more about them.             # ls -l /dev/rhel/root /dev/mapper/rhel-root
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Aug  4 11:10 /dev/mapper/rhel-root -> ../dm-0   I really appreciate your help, thank you so much.